# Scale out a message broker subscriber preventing the double message

Tags: rabbitmq, azureservicebus, messagebroker

I was thinking about a classical message broker (ex. RabbitMQ or Azure Service Bus), used in the pub/sub mode.

Let's talk about this example:

> -Publisher 1 (Example order emitter)
>
> -Subscriber A (Billing)
>
> -Subscriber B (Shipment)

What will happen if I want to scale out one subscriber (Ex. the subscriber B)?

For sure I will have this combination:

> -Publisher 1 (Example order emitter)
>
> -Subscriber A (Billing)
>
> -Subscriber B - node 1 (Shipment)
>
> -Subscriber B - node 2 (Shipment)

Which pattern should be used to prevent the message broker will send the same message to both nodes of the subscriber 2?

Of course i am not referring to some API of the services I listed as example but I am imaging the classical use case when there is a message broker and some of the subscriber should scale out.

Answer (score 1):

When adding instances of the same logical node, you're scaling out, not up. Both brokers support the [Competing Consumers pattert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/competing-consumers) and would not require anything special when scaling **out**. Messages will be handled by a single instance only, unless fail to do so in a timely fashion (in Azure Service Bus case) or were not completed successfully.

Comment: Thank you! I used scale-up in a wrong way (my english grammar fault). I meant obviously horizontal scaling.

Comment: This is definitely the feature i was looking for from Service Bus that could solve the use case I've exposed :
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding.md

Comment: Auto-forwarding will forward w/o giving an option to process on the original subscription. I.e. it's either process the message from the subscription queue, or forward it on. But not both. Be aware of that.

Comment: Yes, I have considered it (I have already read your nice article https://www.serverless360.com/blog/auto-forwarding-a-hidden-gem-of-service-bus).
Is there in Azure Portale for the Service Bus  any way to "chain" a queue to a topic subscription without to create an explicit service that make use of Azure SDK just for autoforward messages without consume it?

Comment: The portal doesn't currently support that. You could use some of the tools available around [ServiceBus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases/latest), [Queue Explorer](https://www.cogin.com/mq/download.php), [Serverless360](https://www.serverless360.com/), etc.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a company called [Solace](https://dev.solace.com), we make message brokers.  Your use case is fairly typical, and pretty easy to architect.  As Sean said, this is competing consumers.  Here's how you'd configure this:

Since your example messages are **Orders**, I'm assuming you don't want to lose these and therefore would need to use *persistent* messaging.  In Solace, when messages land on a Queue, they are persisted.  Therefore:

- your Publisher 1 would be publishing on an "orders" topic (e.g. `orders/new/[ORDER_ID]` )
- you would configure two queues (`qa` and `qb`):

  - add a subscription for topic `orders/new/*` on each queue
  - the 2nd queue would be configured as *non-exclusive* which permits round-robin or load-balanced delivery to all connected consumers
- Subscriber A would bind to `qa`, and Subscribers B1 and B2 would bind to `qb`

Due to pub/sub mechanics, each queue would receive a copy of the message.  For efficiency, persistent storage in Solace is all pointer-based (via reference count) so each message is only written once on the disk even if it's copied across multiple queues.  (unlike Rabbit which writes each copy to disk).

Adding more consumers/subscribers to `qb` would load-balance across them all dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution look like to add a Queue as subscriber of a topic in order to balance messages between multiple nodes of the same service.

In this way I should know before if I would scale out that service since it will change my programming model about how I will use the Message Broker client API.

-What is the best practice? Never use directly a subscription to a topic but put a queue in the middle for eventually scale out the receiver in different nodes?

As I can see Solace provide a way to declare a queue as subscription for a topic and consume messages from the queue. What about Azure Service Bus and Rabbit MQ, can I configure them in that way?

Thank you for your patience